# Проблемы при сборки дефолтного шаблона через bitrix/cli

Tags: битрикс, npm, битрикс24, bitrixcli

Решил кастомизировать компанент `intranet.user.profile` в частности шаблон `widget`. Для чего перекинул данный шаблон на рабочий стол и далее попытался собрать его через `bitrix/cli` выполнив команду `bitrix build`. Далее после сбоки перекинул папку на сервер и увидел такие ошибки

```
babel-external-helpers.js:433 Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
    at Object._inherits [as inherits] (babel-external-helpers.js:433:1)
    at widget.js:45:3
    at widget.js:156:7
    at widget.js:918:24
_inherits @ babel-external-helpers.js:433
(anonymous) @ widget.js:45
(anonymous) @ widget.js:156
(anonymous) @ widget.js:918
VM4421:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init')
    at <anonymous>:4:33
    at Function.ready (ready.js:22:5)
    at <anonymous>:3:4
    at BX.evalGlobal (core.js:2089:1)
    at runtime.js:116:35
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at runtime.js:116:14
```

В чём может быть дело, ведь я вообще ничего не правил в нём, а просто выполнил сборку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, нужно было наличие папки /bitrix/modules и /bitrix/js без них собирать коректно не будет